# Knockout - Foreach binding - How to reflect updated value in HTML

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have a observableArray variable which is having array like below:

```
self.EmployeeNames = ko.observableArray([]);
self.EmployeeNames.push({id: 1, name: 'Jasmine', isActive: false});
self.EmployeeNames.push({id: 2, name: 'Jhon', isActive: true});
self.EmployeeNames.push({id: 3, name: 'juliet', isActive: false});
```

And in my application inside HTML, I bind it using `Knockout foreach` binding as shown below:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: EmployeeNames">
  <div class="container" data-bind="text: $data.name, css: {active: isActive}, click: $parent.setEmployeeToActive">
  </div>
</div>
```

In above code, as you see when isActive is set to true for any of the employee, a css class is applied.

Now when I click on another employee name, it should set the isActive to true for that employee and css class should be updated accordingly.

In order to achieve this, I have `click binding` and whenever user click on the employeeName, I just update the array as shown below:

```
self.setEmployeeToActive = function(selectedEmp) {
    self.EmployeeNames().forEach(function(emp){
      if(emp.id === selectedEmp.id) {
        emp.isActive = true;
      }
      else {
        emp.isActive = false;
      }
    });

    self.EmployeeNames.valueHasMutated();
  };
```

But it is not reflected in HTML.

I tried with `valueHasMutated` but no luck.

[Demo Code](https://jsfiddle.net/p58kun9a/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The members of the array elements must also be observable.

```
self.EmployeeNames.push({id: ko.observable(1), name: ko.observable('Jasmine'), isActive: ko.observable(false)});
```

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5k1hcgq6/)

Comment: I don't think members should also be observable. If my main array is observable it should be refrlected in HTML whenever that observable array changes.

Comment: "Simply putting an object into an observableArray doesn’t make all of that object’s properties themselves observable. Of course, you can make those properties observable if you wish, but that’s an independent choice. An observableArray just tracks which objects it holds, and notifies listeners when objects are added or removed." (from https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

Comment: Well, I tried other solutions but no luck. But by making properties Observable, it works fine.